# How to restrict the level of privileges of applications on jailbroken devices?

Tags: jailbreak

This question is related to [this other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15009/do-apps-on-jailbroken-ios-devices-have-uncontrolled-access-to-all-my-data).

After you have jailbroken your device, you have root access to your device and so do apps that you install.

Can you change the account that an application runs with after you have installed it? This would allow to use an account with less privileges.

If it's possible, then how do you grant/revoke access to data (address book, emails, settings) and APIs (install keyboard hooks, issue network request)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone would have to write a [sandbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_%28computer_security%29) for jailbroken programs, which would be extremely ironic, because the point of jailbreaking was to escape the sandbox. Normal apps still run under the `mobile` user when you're jailbroken, though, so there's nothing to worry about there. All jailbreak packages have full access to anything, and there's currently nothing you can do about that. Just play it safe, and only install trusted packages from reputable developers/repositories. A related question that I answered on the same subject can be found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/41990/18387).

Comment: I see your point. But if I wanted to, could I change the user account that is used to run an application? Or does the springboard always spawn child processes for apps using the `mobile` user account?

Comment: Springboard runs under the `mobile` user and all apps run under the `mobile` user. In fact, most everything is going to run under `wireless` (for cellular data) or `mobile`. Mostly daemons and system tasks run under `root`. Some JailBreak packages need root access (for example, SBSettings). You can't change the user which apps run under without modifying SpringBoard, and I wouldn't recommend doing it.